# Print an 'x' in the board at the coords of the input

Tags: python-3.x, printing, tic-tac-toe

```py
def set_board_up(stones_per_player = 4):
    curr_player = PLAYER_1
    
    fila = "+---+---+---+"
    columna = "|   |   |   |"
    print(fila)
    for i in range(BSIZ):
        print(columna)
        print(fila)
    
    end = False
    i,j=input("Current player, select valid coords ( i j ) for your stone: ").split()
    i = int(i)
    j = int(j)
    
    valid_coords = False
    
    while not valid_coords:
       
        if i not in range(BSIZ+1) or j not in range(BSIZ+1) or i == 0 or j == 0:
            print("The coords you have selected are not valid, please select valid coords:")
            i, j = input().split()
            i = int(i)
            j = int(j)
            
        else:
            valid_coords = True
            print("Your stone is now located at", i, j)
            
            print("X") # Here is where I need help.
```

I don't know how to print the `"X"` in the board I have defined.

I tried to make the board in another way but I don't really know how to start.

Comment: How you reposition the cursor depends on your OS and console. Some platforms understand ANSI codes. `curses` is one library that could be used for this. It's meant for Linux. You can find additional libraries that add in support for Windows.

Comment: Do you need the X to go in the board you've already printed, or is it okay to print a new board with the X in the correct position?